# How to sort a nested map by inner keys descending order and then by inner values in ascending order?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator, nested-map

I have a nested map `Map<String, Map<String, Integer>` for example

("Samsung", ("Note", 30))

("Samsung", ("Galaxy", 20))

("Apple", ("Iphone", 40))

I need to sort the map by **inner key alphabetically in descending** (in this example case - the model name)

and if two names are equal then I have to sort the **inner values in ascending** (in this case - the price).

My sorting by far is like this:

> map.entrySet().stream.forEach(entry -> entry.getValue().entrySet().stream()
>   .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getKey, Comparator.reverseOrder()))

And I know I have to add `.thenComparing()`, but I don't know how to proceed next.

Comment: You want to sort data in descending order of Model name ; and if Madel name are same then on ascending order of price .. Right ?

Comment: @Ajinkya No, I think the model names don't have to be the same.

Comment: then on what basis do you have to sort these data ? on BrandName and Price ?

Comment: @Ajinkya I am telling you, first on brand name and then by their price.

Comment: This does not make any sense, sort based on two properties? Could you please elaborate on your question a bit more?

Comment: @MehrdadHosseinNejad If they key names are equal, then I must sort the values

Comment: What sort of structure would you like your final sorted data to be in?

Answer (score 0):

You write a CustomComparator as Follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public int compare(Object obj1  , Object obj2){

        Map<String, Map<String, Integer> > map1 = (Map<String, Map<String, Integer>) obj1;
        Map<String, Map<String, Integer> > map2 = (Map<String, Map<String, Integer>) obj2;
        Map.Entry e1 = (Map.Entry)map1.entrySet();
        Map.Entry e2 = (Map.Entry)map2.entrySet();
        String brand1 = (String)e1.getKey();
        String brand2 = (String)e2.getKey();
        Map.Entry e3 = (Map.Entry)e1.getValue();
        Map.Entry e4 = (Map.Entry)e3.getValue();
        Integer price1 =(Integer) e3.getValue();
        Integer price2 =(Integer) e4.getValue();

        if(brand2.compareTo(brand1) != 0){
            return brand2.compareTo(brand1);
        }else{
            price1.compareTo(price2);
        }
      }
    }
```

This Compactor will sort data in descending order of brand name first And if two brand having same name then for that it will sort in ascending order of price .

You have to add your data in TreeMap as follows

`Set data = new TreeSet(new CustomComparator());
  //Add your data here in data object`

Comment: @Методи Владимиров is sorting logic implemented here in CustomComaprator class is same as per your need ?

Comment: @Ajinya I think yes, I just need to implement it to see and test.

Comment: @Ajinya I don't know why, but I can't access and I don't have .getKey() method for map1 and map2, neither the value.

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров you have import java.util.*

Comment: Yes i have.., at the very top

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров Sorry my bad Please try this updated code now.

Comment: and now I am trying to place the custom class name inside .sorted(...) in the pipeline, but I get `expression expected`

Comment: Lets Discuss in Chat  : https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206852/man-ki-baat

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров You have to create a TreeMap with CustomCmparator and add all data in that map It will get sorted automatically

Comment: I can't my reputation is lower than 20 :(

Comment: @МетодиВладимиров is your all data of Map<String, Map<String, Integer> object is stored inside a List?

Comment: No it isn't. Actually it is a field property inside a class.